# <Finding the volume in a cylinder that is intersected by a plane

Tags: integration, volume

I have a homework question that goes as follows.

Let $V = \{(x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 4 \text{ and } 0 \leq z \leq 4\}$ be a cylinder and let $P$ be the plane through $(4,0,2), (0,4,2)$, and $(-4,-4,4)$. Compute the volume
of $C$ below the plane $P$.

So I have these points and I set up my $a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0$ where $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a point in the plane and $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ is perpendicular.

I then got two vectors that go between two points, namely: $PQ = <(0-4, (4-0), (2,-2)> = <-4, 4, 0>$ and $PR = <(-4-4), (-4-0), (4,-2)> = <-8,-4,2>$.

I then get the cross product of them to get $<8,8,48>$ which is the coefficient in my equation of the plane:

$$8(x-4) + 8(y-0) + 48(z-2)=0$$ I think that this is the equation of my plane. Is it?

Where do I go from here? I have a feeling I'm supposed to make a triple integral with the function being $8(x-4)  + 8(y-0) + 48(z-2)=0$ and my limits being something to do with the cylinder but I am not sure about it at all. I think my $z$ limits are $0$ to $4$. Is that right?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you made a mistake in your second vector when computing the direction of the plane:

$$PR=(-8,-4,2)$$

and your cross product doesn't look correct even with your vector $PR$.

Now the volume can be set up like this:

$$\iint_S z dxdy$$

where $S$ is the projection of the volume to the $xy$ plane and $z$ is the upper limit of $z$ which is the plane represented by $z$.

In fact, you will need to check whether the plane is below $z=4$ in the confined region. After some trick you will see the plane is really below $z=4$. That's why the $z=4$ would not be in your integral any more.

The triple integral is

$$\int\int\int_0^z dzdxdy $$

where $z$ is exactly the plane. That is why I wrote the double integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KittyL I have changed the numbers in my question so they should be correct now.

I am afraid I don't really understand what you have said there. I thought this was a triple integral problem? Where does my equation of the plane come into it and where does my 0 - 4 size of z come in?

Sorry for being slow, I think I may have fried my brain revising for these exams!

Comment: @user113463: I edited the part that involves triple integral. And by the way, your equation with polar coordinate is correct, except that you forgot the $16-$, and the order of integration signs should be $\int_0^{2\pi}\int^2_0$.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $\vec{a}=\langle-4,4,0\rangle$ and $\vec{b}=\langle-8,-4,2\rangle$, then $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\langle8,8,48\rangle$.

Then we can take $\vec{n}=\langle1,1,6\rangle$ as a normal vector to the plane, so substituting in the coordinates of one of the points gives $x+y+6z=16$.

Now you can use polar coordinates or rectangular coordinates to find the volume,

since the base of the solid is the region in the xy-plane bounded by the circle $x^2+y^2=4$,

and the height of the solid is given by $z=\frac{1}{6}(16-x-y)$.

Comment: Thanks for this @user84413 ! 

What is my integral? Another user has said it would be z dx dy. Is that right? Is the whole point of the equation of the plane to find out z? If I use polar, would it be from 0 <= r <= 2 and 0 <= $\theta$ <= $2 pi$?

Comment: @user113463 You're welcome, and your limits for polar coordinates are correct.  As you say, you wanted to find the equation of the plane to find z, which gives the height of the solid above each point in the base.

Comment: So just to make sure I've got this right... My integral should be:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}  1/6 (r cos \theta - r sin \theta) ,r dr d \theta $$

Right?